# Swiper React Breakpoints on React Page Load (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, breakpoints, bootstrap-5, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper React](https://swiperjs.com/react) with React.

As far as I'm aware, I'm not able to control the 'slides per view' with Bootstrap. If I could, I'd simply create the necessary columns and put the swiper slides inside them.

Instead I'm using the Swiper JS breakpoints. The breakpoints work and the 'slides per view' adjust as required, however, on page load, the slides show as 100%, and then shrink to the correct size - it's causing a horrible effect: [VIDEO PREVIEW](https://streamable.com/08bkla)

If anybody has any idea how to fix this I'd appreciate it - Code below:

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Seo from "../components/seo"

import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

import ProjectImage from "../images/project-image.jpg"

// import Swiper core and required modules
import { Pagination, A11y } from 'swiper';

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Seo title="Home" />
      <Container className="py-5">
      <Swiper
      modules={[Pagination, A11y]}
      spaceBetween={50}
      breakpoints={{
        0: {
          width: 0,
          slidesPerView: 1,
        },
        768: {
          width: 768,
          slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        1200: {
          width: 1200,
          slidesPerView: 3,
        },
      }}
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>
      <div class="card chosen-project">
                                <img src={ProjectImage} class="card-img-top" alt="..."/>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title mt-2">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
                                    <p class="card-text mt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                                    <div class="mt-4 mb-2">
                                        <span class="badge rounded-pill">Lorem</span>
                                        <span class="badge rounded-pill">Ipsum</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer bg-white">
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link muted">Installer</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Source</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
      ...
    </Swiper>
      </Container>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not add 'width' option in breakpoints. Instead use what option you would like to add in the resolution object directly, eg:

```
<Swiper
      slidesPerView={1}
      spaceBetween={30}
      slidesPerGroup={1}
      breakpoints={{
    // when window width is >= 576px
        576: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
        },
    // when window width is >= 768px
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
        },
    // when window width is >= 1024px
        1024: {
          spaceBetween: 10,
          slidesPerView: 3,
        },
        1280: {
          slidesPerGroup: 2,
          slidesPerView: 4,
        },
      }}
      pagination={{
        clickable: true,
      }}
      navigation
      modules={[Pagination, Navigation]}
      className="mySwiper"
    >
```

For more information, you can check the [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#navigation), it is for VanillsJS, but  breakpoints work in React as well.